# Will wordpress tools import do everything I need to copy one site to another

Tags: users, migration, import

I'm copying all the content and users to a new domain (the current site will stay live, I'm not getting rid of that one) and I was thinking about just setting up a new wordpress install and using the wordpress tools > export > all content (from the old site) and tools > import (on the new site) to copy everything over.

That way I can install a fresh version of wordpress and just go through the normal setup process without having to worry about manually creating new databases and updating URLs and whatnot.

Will this not work for some reason? Will it populate the database with the old users (who also need to be copied over) and their passwords and user roles? Will it send them emails prompting them to create new accounts?

Comment: I don't think the built in export option will be able to transfer all your data to a new website. Stuffs such as images need to be taken care of by another method, such as manually copying or using third-party plugins.

Answer (score 0):

On the Tools > Export page it says:

> This format, which we call WordPress eXtended RSS or WXR, will contain your posts, pages, comments, custom fields, categories, and tags.

So this will not be sufficient option for you. You need to migrate the database and that requires updating links to reflect the new domain and file structure.

You can migrate the site [manually](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) or use one of [many plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/migrate/) dedicated to this job.

If you want to move just the users to the new fresh installation follow [this guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-import-and-export-wordpress-users/).